# jquery .post not working

Tags: jquery, post

High!

I just wondered why this won't work?

```
$.post($("#jsCheckoutForm_1b").attr("action"), { 
    sLoginName: $("#sLoginName").val(), 
    sPassword: $("#sPassword").val() 
    }, function(sData){
        alert(sData);
    }
);
```

the fun thing is that if i hard code the action in stead of using `$("#jsCheckoutForm_1b").attr("action")`, the form is submitting. Alerting `$("#jsCheckoutForm_1b").attr("action")` does work fine (meaning it displays the right url to use).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Firebug or a similar tool to see where the $.post action goes? Saying it "won't work"  could mean many things.

Comment: Let me back up a bit - my first answer was a case of fingers speeding past my brain. ;) What browser(s) are you using? This works fine for me in the Firefox 3.5.7 and IE 6.0 (meaning I can successfully use `$.post` to post to the url specified by `$('#id').attr('action')`).

Comment: hi jeff!
yes i am using firebug and there wasn't any post displaying there. i found that strange and then remembered that firefox just had installed a beta version of the new firebug. 

so what i then did is reinstalled the old one and now, tahtaah, everyting is working fine. The form is forming, posts are posting ;)

Thanks for your help though. 

by the way, the code didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I would cache some variables and test them.

```
var form=$('#jsCheckoutForm_1b'),
  url=form.attr('action'),
  login=$('#sLoginName'),
  password=$('#sPassword');

console.log(form, url);
form.submit(function(){
  $.post(url,
    {sLoginName: login.val(), sPassword: password.val()},
    function(sData){

  });  
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to have `return false;` on the onclick function of the submit button.